# Error while generating signed apk: Unable to open as zip archive - Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, zipalign, signed-apk

I have created an android application in Eclipse, however while running the zipalign command to export it as a signed apk, the following error shows up and the apk is not generated. Please guide me on how to fix this error? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: may be eclipse is no more support android. try android studio to export apk

Comment: No. I can't do this because out project manager want to use with Eclipse. And eclipse is still supporting android. Thanks for your answer. Is there any other solve?

Comment: You can use proguard in eclipse to make zipalign apk. use it.

Comment: export an unsigned apk from eclipse and then using command manually generate signed and zipaligned apk.

Comment: #Sunil Parmar - I have already using proguard but it's still got that error. Can you show me how to make it right.?

Comment: Mr.shadow-droid Can you show me how to do with command line manually generated signed and zipaligned apk?